# Unity - Git LFS - "This repository is over its data quota" on new repository

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, github, git-lfs

The error

> This repository is over its data quota. Account responsible for LFS
> bandwidth should purchase more data packs to restore access.

keeps appearing, even after I deleted the repo, created a new empty one, deleted the assets that were causing the problem and even deleted the .git folder on the project. And not only that, the error appears with the first push on any new empty repo. I'm using github as my remote

I already used

> git lfs uninstall

and

> git filter-branch

This is the screenshot from the console.

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone faces the same issue, github does this:

> Bandwidth quota If you use more than 1 GB of bandwidth per month
> without purchasing a data pack, Git LFS support is disabled on your
> account until the next month.

https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/about-storage-and-bandwidth-usage